# How can I add component with dot at storybook?

Tags: storybook, nextjs-storybook

I want to add a component with dot like react component. For example like Button.Icon. If there is a doc exist at storybook's docs probably I miss it.

When I added it manually its not working like react component.
`<Button> <Button.Icon> ... </Button.Icon> </Button>`

Comment: What did you end up doing about this?